# C# instantiating a Class that hold a ListArray into a method

Tags: c#

I am trying to instantiate an instance of the ListEx class in my `StoreNames()` method in order to get a list of names and store it in the class `ListEx` so other methods can access them. I recieve an error that I cannot convert a void to an int. Can someone shed a little light on this?

```
public class ListEx
{
    List<string> name = new List<string>();
}

string StoreNames()
{
   ListEx nm = new ListEx();
   List<string> tmpName = new List<string>();

   nm.name.add = tmpName.Add(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

////////////////new Code//////////////////////

```
class Program
{
    public static List<string> localList = new List<string>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> a = new List<string>();
        SortName(a);
        Console.Read();
    }
    public static List<string> StoreName(List<string> aString)
    {
        aString = new List<string>();
        localList.Add("c");
        localList.Add("a");
        localList.Add("b");
        localList.Add("d");

        foreach (string s in localList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.Read();
        return aString;
    }
    public static List<string> SortName(List<string> aString)
    {
        StoreName(aString);
        localList.Sort();
        foreach (string s in localList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        return localList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or (after reading your post again:)

```
public class ListEx
{
   public List<string> name = new List<string>();
}

void StoreName()
{
  ListEx nm = new ListEx();
  List<string> localList = new List<string>();

  localList.Add ( "whatever" );

  nm.name = localList;
}

void StoreNameShort()
{
  ListEx nm = new ListEx();

  nm.name.Add( "whatever" );
}
```

hth

Mario

Comment: It says that nm.name is inaccessable due to its protection level. But this is actually the school of thought I had.

Comment: have you seen that I chnaged ListEx.name to public ? It should compile fine. Also note that I chnaged the type of StoreName to void instead of string (since you are not returning anything)

Comment: Thanks Mario, that worked!!! I guess my understanding was not that great of the problem I was trying to solve.

Comment: Note that having a public field is generally a *very bad idea*. If you *really* need the `ListEx` class (which I'm still not convinced about) you should either have a property to allow the list to be replaced/fetched, or you should create methods to allow a limited set of operations on the list.

Comment: above is my new code with your approach, is this along the terms you were thinking? Thanks.

Comment: @Jon: Sorry, forgot to point that out! But you are rith of course!

Answer (score 2):

Well, in this line:

```
nm.name.add = huh.Add(Console.ReadLine());
```

- ... you're trying to use a private field, which won't work unless `StoreNames` is within ListEx.
- You're then trying to assign to a subfield/property of `ListEx`... what are you expecting `add` to refer to?
- You're trying to use `huh.Add` when you haven't shown what `huh` is
- You're trying to assign the value returned by `huh.Add` to `nm.name.add`, and I suspect that `Add` has a void return type.

In other words, it's pretty broken. It's not really clear what you're trying to do here, why you need `ListEx`, where `StoreNames` is, or why you're trying to assign the return value of the `Add` method to a field/property. Does `ListEx` *really* just consist of a private field? It's not going to be much use if so.

Comment: Thank. I was attempting to store the names I recieved in a seperate class outside of the program with the main statment, then access it with other methods that would allow me to add, delete, ect. Most likely this is the "hard way" and perhaps I should just declare a global variable within my program, instead of this approach?

Comment: @jpavlov: A global variable is almost never the way forward, but I still don't see what purpose `ListEx` is meant to serve. Why can't you use `List<string>` directly?

Comment: ListEx was suppossed to be the collection where the List of Names are stored after collection. Afterwards, individual methods would call on to manipulate them, ex.(sorting, deleting, adding more).

Comment: @jpavlov: `List<string>` supports sorting, deleting, adding etc. What is `ListEx` meant to add on top of that?

Comment: It is like a holder for all of the information it collects, so other methods can access the same data, work on it, and return it to there. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @jpavlov: Not really... that still sounds like something you could just use a `ListEx` for. Put it this way: if you looked at everywhere you're using `ListEx` and just replaced it with `List<string>`, what would change or break?

Comment: Very good question, I will refactor and give that approach a try right now.

Answer (score 0):

`nm.name.Add( Console.ReadLine());` ?